# How to get and display pdf file from Amazon S3 with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

I am using this code do get data from Amazon S3:

```
var s3 = new aws.S3({
    access_key_id: system.config.amazonS3.accessKey,
    secret_access_key: system.config.amazonS3.secretAccessKey
});
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'b9ca6cca65f34bf60d3ffalse.pdf'};
//    var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('./file.pdf');
    s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else
            console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

And it will return something like this:

```
{ AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 'Fri, 09 Sep 2016 12:08:18 GMT',
  ContentLength: '688609',
  ETag: '"3063770da82053b9c97fe5f2b7b923ac"',
  ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  Metadata: { fieldname: 'files' },
  Body: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 36 0d 25 e2 e3 cf d3 0d 0a 32 37 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0d 3c 3c 2f 46 69 6c 74 65 72 2f 46 6c 61 74 65 44 65 63 6f 64 65 2f 46 69 72 ... > }
```

How can I create pdf file to display the data(response)?

Comment: refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

Answer (score 0):

You can generate PDF using [jsPDF()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)

```
   var doc = new jsPDF();
   for(var attribute in data){
       doc.text(35, 25, attribute +": " + data[attribute]);
   }
   doc.save('DataOutput.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

The body part of your response contains the PDF file content as a buffer. If you want to convert it to text you need to convert it to [Unit8 array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array). Then pass that Unit8 array to any of the PDF reader packages in Node.js. To achieve the best results you can use [PDF.JS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/).

```
s3Client.getObject({Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME', Key: 'FILE_NAME'}, function (err, data) {
if (err) cb(err);
getText(data.Body).then(function (text) { //data.Body will contain the content as buffer.
cb(null, {item: text}); //text will contain the text corresponding to the buffer.
}).catch(function(e){
cb('something went wrong !');
});
});
```

In the getText() function am using PDFJS to extract the text from PDF file. In order to use PDF.jS in the backend, you should require the library *pdfjs-dist* using `const pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist');`

```
//getText() function
function getText(typedarray) {

    //PDFJS should be able to read this typedarray content
    var pdf = pdfjsLib.getDocument(new Uint8Array(typedarray));
    return pdf.then(function (pdf) {
        // get all pages text
        var maxPages = pdf._pdfInfo.numPages;
        var countPromises = [];
        // collecting all page promises
        for (var j = 1; j <= maxPages; j++) {
            var page = pdf.getPage(j);

            countPromises.push(page.then(function (page) {
                // add page promise
                var textContent = page.getTextContent();

                return textContent.then(function (text) {

                    var pageContent = text.items.map(function (s) {
                        return s.str;
                    }).join(' '); // value page text
                    pageContent = pageContent.replace(/</g, '');
                    return ((page.pageNumber > 1) ? (' #pagebreak# ' + pageContent) : pageContent);
                });
            }));
        }
        // Wait for all pages and join text
        return Promise.all(countPromises).then(function (texts) {
            return texts.join('');
        });
    });
}
```